# Google Maps overlays don't move when I pan the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, overlay, pan

#### UPDATE 07/12/2011: I figured it out. Will post solution as soon as I'm finished with the implementation.

I am creating an Android application that will display the location of several users on a Google Map. The users are currently represented as blue and green dots on the map. When you tap the blue dot representing your location, a custom overlay appears on the map that says "Current Location"

[image: http://imgur.com/7S1Bg]

My problem is that when I scroll or zoom the map the overlay with "Current Location" remains in the same spot while the map moves below it. I want it to move with the map so that the popup is always directly above the blue dot, like in this example:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_ewindow.htm.

Here is how my map project is laid out:

I have an Activity that extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity. This activity has as a member a com.google.android.maps.MapView object. I manage the overlays with an AdjacentMapOverlayList (which extends ItemizedOverlay).

Here is my code when a user clicks on the blue icon:

```
/*
 * Handle tap events.
 * 
 * @param index the item that was tapped
 */
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    Log.d(TAG, "User clicked something");

    // get the item that was tapped
    OverlayItem item = (OverlayItem) getItem(index);

    // cast it
    AdjacentUserOverlay overlay = (AdjacentUserOverlay) item;

    // get the point from the item
    GeoPoint geo = overlay.getPoint();
    Point pt = m_mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geo, null);

    // display the dialog
    m_userPopupDialog.show(pt.x, pt.y);

    // true dat
    return true;
}
```

I am guessing that I need to intercept map movement events and move the popup dialogs manually, but there has to be an easier way. Can anyone explain how to do this? I'll be on all day if you need any additional information. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Are you only moving the current location pop up? If so then its pretty easy, just re-display the pop up at the new co-ordinates every time you get new location information.

Comment: I got it. Will post the solution soon. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my class that extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay:

```
package com.joshuawitter.maps;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
import com.joshuawitter.Base64;

/*
 * UsersOverlay.java
 * 
 * Description: The Google Maps overlay that displays the users on the map screen.
 * 
 * Author: Joshua Witter
 */

public class UsersOverlay extends Overlay {

    private static final String TAG = "Josh-UsersOverlay";

    // the activity that called this overlay
    private Activity m_caller;

    // the currently selected User
    private UserOnMap m_selectedUser;

    // list of User locations
    private ArrayList<UserOnMap> m_Users;

    // set the list of Users
    public void setUsers(ArrayList<UserOnMap> users) {

        // set the list of Users
        this.m_Users = users;
    }

    /*
     * Parameterized constructor.
     * 
     * @param caller the activity that created this overlay
     * @param Users a list of the Users to display
     */
    public UsersOverlay(Activity caller) {
        super();

        // reference the caller
        m_caller = caller;

        // make a new list of Users
        m_Users = new ArrayList<UserOnMap>(0);
    }

    /*
     * User tapped the map.
     * 
     * @param geoPoint the location the user tapped
     * @param mapView the map itself
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView) {

        // get the User that was tapped
        UserOnMap user = getTappedUser(mapView, geoPoint);

        // if the user tapped on a User
        if (null != user) {

            // if this User is not already selected, select it
            m_selectedUser = (m_selectedUser != user) ? user : null;
        }

        // otherwise the user tapped nothing
        else {

            // deselect the selected user
            m_selectedUser = null;
        }

        // call through to the parent
        return super.onTap(geoPoint, mapView);
    }

    /*
     * Draw the overlay on the map.
     * 
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw on
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param shadow should we draw the shadow?
     */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        // draw the User icons
        drawUserIcons(canvas, mapView);

        // call the parent draw method
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }

    /*
     * Draw the User icons on the map.
     * 
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw on
     * @param mapView the map view
     */
    private void drawUserIcons(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView) {

        // loop through the users
        for (UserOnMap user : m_Users) {

            // draw the icon for the User
            drawUserIcon(canvas, mapView, user);
        }

        // draw the selected User last so that it is on top
        if (null != m_selectedUser) {
            drawUserBubble(canvas, mapView, m_selectedUser);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Draw a User bubble overlay.
     * 
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw on
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param user the User we are displaying the information for
     */
    private void drawUserBubble(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, UserOnMap user) {

        // get the overlay point
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Point pt = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(user.getLocation(), pt);

        // get the bubble bitmap ready
        Bitmap bubbleBitmap = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(m_caller.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.user_bubble);

        // get the dimensions of the bubble
        int height = bubbleBitmap.getHeight();
        int width = bubbleBitmap.getWidth();

        // calculate the offsets
        int xValue = pt.x - (width / 2);
        int yValue = pt.y - height - 20;

        // draw the icon
        canvas.drawBitmap(bubbleBitmap, xValue, yValue, null);

        // get the paint object
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(24);

        // draw the text
        canvas.drawText("Current Location", xValue + 30, yValue + 33, paint);
    }

    /*
     * Draw a User icon overlay.
     * 
     * @param canvas the canvas to draw on
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param user the User we are displaying the icon for
     */
    private void drawUserIcon(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
            UserOnMap user) {

        // get the overlay point
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Point pt = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(user.getLocation(), pt);

        // get the icon
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m_caller.getResources(),
                user.getIconResource());

        // get the dimensions of the icon
        int height = icon.getHeight();
        int width = icon.getWidth();

        // calculate the offsets
        int xValue = pt.x - (width / 2);
        int yValue = pt.y - height;

        // draw the icon
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, xValue, yValue, null);
    }

    /*
     * Determine which User was tapped by the user.
     * 
     * @param tapPoint where the user tapped
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param UserOnMap the User was tapped, null if none
     */
    private UserOnMap getTappedUser(MapView mapView, GeoPoint tapPoint) {

        // get the screen coordinates that match our tap
        Point tapScreenCoordinates = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, tapScreenCoordinates);

        // loop through the User icons
        for (UserOnMap user : m_Users) {

            // if this is the currently selected User
            if (user == m_selectedUser) {

                // if we tapped its bubble
                if (hitUserBubble(mapView, tapPoint, user)) {

                    // we found the User
                    Log.d(TAG, "User " + user.getLastName() + " was tapped (bubble)");
                    return user;

                }
            }

            // otherwise if we tapped the icon for an User 
            if (hitUserIcon(mapView, tapPoint, user)) {

                // return the User
                Log.d(TAG, "User " + user.getLastName() + " was tapped (icon)");
                return user;
            }
        }

        // return the tapped User
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Determine if an User's icon was tapped by the user.
     * 
     * @param tapPoint where the user tapped
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param User the User we are checking
     * @param boolean true if the icon for this User was tapped
     */
    private boolean hitUserIcon(MapView mapView, GeoPoint tapPoint,
            UserOnMap user) {

        // get the screen coordinates that match our tap
        Point tapScreenCoordinates = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, tapScreenCoordinates);

        // get the screen coordinates for the User's location
        Point iconScreenCoordinates = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(user.getLocation(),
                iconScreenCoordinates);

        // get the icon for the User
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m_caller.getResources(),
                user.getIconResource());

        // calculate the icon hit box size
        int xValue = 50;
        int yValue = 50;

        // create a rectangle representing our icon
        RectF iconRectangle = new RectF();
        iconRectangle.set(-xValue, -yValue, xValue, yValue);
        iconRectangle.offset(iconScreenCoordinates.x, iconScreenCoordinates.y);

        // return true if the user tapped on the icon for this User
        return (iconRectangle.contains(tapScreenCoordinates.x,
                tapScreenCoordinates.y));
    }

    /*
     * Determine if an User's bubble was tapped by the user.
     * 
     * @param tapPoint where the user tapped
     * @param mapView the map view
     * @param User the User we are checking
     * @param boolean true if the bubble for this User was tapped
     */
    private boolean hitUserBubble(MapView mapView, GeoPoint tapPoint,
            UserOnMap user) {

        // get the screen coordinates that match our tap
        Point tapScreenCoordinates = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(tapPoint, tapScreenCoordinates);

        // get the screen coordinates for the User's location
        Point iconScreenCoordinates = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(user.getLocation(),
                iconScreenCoordinates);

        // get the bubble for the User
        Bitmap bubble = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m_caller.getResources(),
                R.drawable.backup_map_current_location);

        // calculate the bubble hit box size
        int xValue = bubble.getWidth() * 2;
        int yValue = bubble.getHeight() * 2;

        // create a rectangle representing our bubble
        RectF iconRectangle = new RectF();
        iconRectangle.set(-xValue, -yValue, xValue, yValue);
        iconRectangle.offset(iconScreenCoordinates.x, iconScreenCoordinates.y);

        // return true if the user tapped on the bubble
        return (iconRectangle.contains(tapScreenCoordinates.x,
                tapScreenCoordinates.y));
    }
}
```

I have a service that is called by my activity (extends MapActivity) that returns a list of Users. I just take that list and use this method:

```
    // for each User we got back
    for (User user: response.getUsers()) {

        // get the location of the User
        GeoPoint userLocation = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (user.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (user.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        // create a map representation of the User
        UserOnMap userOnMap = new UserOnMap(user.getUserId(),
                user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());

        // add the user to the list
        usersOnMap.add(userOnMap);
    }

    // set the overlay to reference this new list
    m_usersOverlay.setUsers(usersOnMap);

    // get the current list of map overlays
    List<Overlay> m_mapOverlays = m_mapView.getOverlays();
    m_mapOverlays.clear();
    m_mapOverlays.add(m_usersOverlay);
    m_mapView.invalidate();
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Please ignore the allocation in the loop, weird variable names, etc, this is not only a rough draft but an obfuscated one at that :-)